# ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_27 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 5)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have some pixel movement data and it has 5 features and 3715489 training samples. I keep getting this error and I don't know what I should make the input_shape for the LSTM.

X_train shape is (3715489,5). Do I need to reshape this?

y_train shape is (3715489, 8)

Here is my code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256,return_sequences=True, input_shape=(5,)))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

print(model.summary())
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100,batch_size=320)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the error,

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_27 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

The LSTM layer expects 3D inputs with a shape of `(batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)`. You can pass `(timesteps, input_dim)` for input_shape argument. But you are setting input_shape (5,). This shape does not include timesteps dimension. Adding an extra dimension to input_shape will solve the problem.

```
#Reshape data
x_train = tf.reshape(x_train,(-1, 1, 5))
y_train = tf.reshape(y_train,(-1, 1, 8))

model = Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(256,return_sequences=True, input_shape=(1,5)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

print(model.summary())
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1,batch_size=320)
```

Please refer to this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM) for more information. Thank you!